# jQuery AJAX request sometimes pending on Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with jQuery AJAX, the request is pending sometimes. I don't know how to triggered this issue, sometimes pending, sometimes OK.

[image]

Request by using $.ajax in jquery. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I had to give response JSON header and using https.

Thanks.

Comment: Also when request in my CMS website is pending, I can't access main page until the request finished, but I can access it in another PC or mobile

Comment: Find out why it’s pending?  My guess is that it’s happening on your server.  Debug those specific callbacks in your server code

Comment: I had do that, when its pending, there no request sent in server side, so I cant debug backend code when pending is appear. In localhost, I must restart apache to finish pending request

Comment: Without your code it just empty talking. If you see request is pending so ajax send request. If it not hitting any related breakpoint on back-end then it may be done to wrong url or something filtering, capturing it before your back-end...may be there is some request handler etc. As an example my fight against CORS: webdav IIS plugin captured OPTION request in-front of back-end code...

Comment: I'm using CI HMVC in backend fyi. Also I had do give breakpoint in first line in method, and in config.php file to make sure request is successfully sent to server. But when pending is appear, no one breakpoint is triggered.

Comment: But weird, when I using Firefox, no request is pending. That's why I said this issue only appear when using Chrome

Comment: @Raissa Ditya Putri Did you solve the problem? I have a similar one.

Answer (score 5):

"Pending" means that your client is still waiting for a response from the server. This is not an issue with your clientside code - it is an issue with your connection or even with the serverside code. cheers!

Comment: But it sometimes triggered, in localhost or dev or production server.

Comment: I'm having this issue on Chrome on localhost with an extremely simple one-character AJAX response. Correct response headers (including content-length) are there, but the status hangs forever on pending and the response doesn't show up. No errors or apparent issues on the backend. Only happens intermittently on Chrome. Does not happen at all on Firefox or Edge. Multiple other complaints about this out there.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly four years after this question was posted, I was having the same issue, except I was using htmx.ajax() to make the AJAX request (which might just be using jQuery AJAX behind the scenes, I'm not sure).

In my case, I am 100% certain that the issue was not with my connection or server side code as the upvoted answer suggests, for several reasons...

- This was occurring when developing on localhost, so no connection issue
- It was working perfectly in Edge and Firefox. (It was also working on Chrome about a quarter of the time, but with no clear indication of when it would or when it wouldn't.)
- Debugging logs on backend indicated the response was being sent out quickly and correctly
- Response was only a single character, so I know it wasn't too big. (I also tried making it bigger just in case it was somehow too small, but that didn't work either.)
- Chrome Dev Tools was able to show the exact content-length and all of the correct response headers, so it had obviously received the response, but the status was hanging indefinitely on pending and it was unable to show the response body.
- This request is only occurring when a page is reached through the back button, and it and the request for the favicon were the only two requests appearing in the Network tab on Dev Tools, so I don't *think* it was an issue with Chrome's TCP connection limit, but I could be wrong about that.

There are quite a few StackOverflow questions and Chromium bug reports floating around out there about different variations of this issue, going back at least as far as 2015. None that I've seen seem to be definitively reproducible or have a concrete solution, but it definitely seems like there's *something* going on somewhere in Chrome causing this.

In my case, adding a half-second timeout before making the request seems to have resolved the issue. That may or may not work for somebody else having this issue (suggestions I saw that worked for others in the past did not work for me), but worth a shot if it's reasonable within your use case.

Comment: adding a half-second timeout before making the request seems to have resolved the issue. THE SAME FOR ME.